# Handle a request header in Django rest framework to get the secret key passed in the header and save it with User table?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have a django backend for a mobile app.

I'm using django rest framework (django-rest-auth), but I'm still writing my own views and logic because the API endpoints are not model based.

The request sent to me has a secret key in the headers which is associated to individual devices registered. Along with it it has post data consisting of device id and other details.

Once I get that header using request.META how can Save it in User model(It'll update everytime user login), so later it can be used as a foreign key to getting all the details like user and associated device.

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
   def get_response_serializer(self):

    if getattr(settings, 'REST_USE_JWT', False):
        response_serializer = JWTSerializer
    else:
        # print(self.request.data)
        response_serializer = serializers.TokenSerializer
        # response_serializer = {'data':response_serializer}
    return response_serializer
   def get_response(self):

    # raise APIException("There was a problem!")
    serializer_class = self.get_response_serializer()
    # print(serializer_class.data)
    try:
        if getattr(settings, 'REST_USE_JWT', False):
            data = {
                'user': self.user,
                'token': self.token
            }
            serializer = serializer_class(instance=data,
                                        context={'request': self.request})
        else:
            print("hello")
            serializer = serializer_class(instance=self.token,
                                        context={'request': self.request})
            print("BYE")
            print(serializer.data)
            # print(self.request.data)
            try:
                # print(serializer.data)
                if 'email' not in self.request.POST:
                    return Response({'data':'message'})

                return Response({'data':serializer.data,'status':1,'message':'Success'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            except ValidationError as exc:
                raise ValidationError({
                        'field_val1': exc.detail,
                    })
    except:
            print("in except")
            raise APIException("There was a problem!")


   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = request
    self.serializer = self.get_serializer(data=self.request.data,
                                          context={'request': request})
    print(self.request.data)

    if self.serializer.is_valid():
        print(request.META)
        self.login()
        return self.get_response()
    else:
        return Response({"data":[],"message":"Credentials are wrong",'status':0})
```

## My User_Model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
"""User model."""

username = None
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
mobile_token = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

objects = UserManager()
```

## My UserManage()

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

```
use_in_migrations = True

def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

    if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Comment: Did you add any field in your `User` model ? Can you add those here?.

Comment: Yes this is my User Model :-  
    class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    mobile_token = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
Now the thing things from the mobile_devices I'll get mobile_token from the header, and I've to update that token in My User model which can be used as a foreign key for other tables.

Comment: I couldn't find that in your question

Comment: I've updated the last comment as well as main Question

Comment: Now the thing things from the mobile_devices I'll get mobile_token from the header, and I've to update that token in My User model which can be used as a foreign key for other tables.

Comment: One quick suggestion for you, **do not ever add huge code snippet to *comment section***

Comment: Are you planning to save the header into `mobile_token` field in your model ?

Comment: Yes, So whenever my login API will call (custom Django-rest-auth), I'll get mobile_token from the header, and I've to save that to User model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an `instance method` and use it **wherever in your `CustomLoginView`** as

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError


class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    def save_header(self):
        headr = self.request.META.get('HTTP_MYHEADER', None)
        if headr is None:
            raise ValidationError('"MYHEADER" is missing in headers"')
        current_user = self.user
        current_user.mobile_token = headr
        current_user.save()

    # your code
```

**UPDATE**
Change your view  as below

```
from rest_auth.views import LoginView
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError


class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    def save_header(self):
        headr = self.request.META.get('HTTP_MYHEADER', None)
        if headr is None:
            raise ValidationError('"MYHEADER" is missing in headers"')
        current_user = self.user
        current_user.mobile_token = headr
        current_user.save()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            self.save_header()
        return response
```

and your payload should be as

```
{
    "email":"myemail@email.com",
    "password":"mypassword"
}
```

**Screenshots**
1. How to add HEADER
[image: Headers in POSTMAN]
2. How to send data in POSTMAN
[image: JSON Payload]

Comment: Django doesn't provide a DB representation for AnonymousUser.
Whenever I try to post data using postman.

Comment: What are all data you send to the server?

Comment: Headers :- key:value
Body:- email:value,password:value

Comment: Use `self.user` instead of `self.request.user`. (I've updated the answer)

Comment: Don't you think that'll give me error ? since user is not defined in my CustomLogin view

Comment: I can see `self.user` in your code. Moreover, how do you verify/validate the user?

Comment: I am using serializer.is_valid() function.
And I tried self.user it's showing me this error :- CustomLoginView dont have attribute 'user'

Comment: I didn't mean *serializer validation*, What I meant is, how do you check whether the request comes from a ***registered user*** or not

Comment: I am not doing that validation yet

Comment: BTW I've also added Custom UserManage() as well.

Comment: You are planning to save the HEADER into a `User` model. It's only possible for **registered users**

Comment: Apart from that, How do we know where to save the HEADER coming from the request?

Comment: Can you give me some suggestions for validating user and saving that mobile_token in via Loginapi?

Comment: Thank you very much, Token is saved. Is there any way that this token can be used as foreign key for other tables?

Comment: I don't gwt that, anyway ask a new question in SO